# Motherboard recommendation for G3258 OC

Tags: processor, motherboard

I am interested to build a new desktop PC having as starting point G3258 CPU overclocked at 4-4.5GHz. It's well known the fact that the overclocking subject regarding this CPU it's pretty twisted. I've read different infos telling that once, this CPU was overclockable on Motherboards with B85, H87, H81, Z87, Z97 chipsets; Lately, I've read about a Win 10 update that cut this possibility but not so sure if this will apply on Z chipset Mobos or not(?)

Having said that, which is in your opinion your Motherboard recommendation in order to use this CPU in OC mode please? (if there is anyone that use a machine with this CPU overclocked); I've studied these:

ASUS Z97M-PLUS

ASUS Z97-K

ASROCK Z97 Anniversary

ASROCK Z97 PRO4

But I can't decide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The G3258 is an unlocked processor on the 1150 socket, so it is not subject to all of the recent BIOS hubbub surrounding Intel's crackdown on overclocking non-K processors on the 1151 (Skylake) socket. As such, it is STILL THE CASE that you can overclock your G3258 on ANY 1150 motherboard with a BIOS that supports OCing, Windows 10 or not.

As such, I recommend the Gigabyte GA-H81M-H. It is a proven overclocker and is currently one of the cheapest boards available for the 1150 socket.

Comment: Thank you for your feed-back, you just gave me a good hint (1151 Skylake) and I think that I'll choose to buy a G4400 CPU 3.3Ghz + a decent Mobo without having in mind to OC because as far as I've read this is a pretty low temperature processor and is good enough for me. B. regards,

Comment: If I may be so bold, let me suggest to you that if you were planning on needing a Haswell (G3258) processor to run at 4+ ghz in order for it to perform as you would like, attempting to replace it with a 3.3ghz processor from Skylake is not going to be sufficient. Skylake enjoys, at best, a 5-10% real world performance gain per clock over Haswell, which would mean it's equivalent to a G3258 running at something more like 3.5ghz. 

Finally, may I ask why you want to use these Pentium CPUs in the first place? Their practical application in modern computers is extremely limited.

Comment: Actually I've re-evaluate the whole thing having as reference point my old Intel Core 2 Duo E6750 2.66GB, HDD 1TB, 4 X Corsair 2GB DDR2, 800MHz, PC2-6400, 5-5-5-18 + MSI R7770-PMD1GD5, AMD Radeon HD 7770 1GB GDDR5, 128bit on Intel DP35DP mainboard, used mostly for image editing. That's why I suppose that a G4400 + 8..16 DDR3/4 + a decent Mobo like  Asus H170 Pro or H170 Plus-D3 + SSD (as OS support), keeping in place the same graphic card, will be more than enough and a visible improvement. Am I right?

Comment: So the biggest problem with your present system is RAM. At only 2gb, you barely have enough for a modern operating system, let alone that + your photo editing. You could attempt to upgrade your setup quite nicely with the following CPUs + an 8gb RAM stick and corresponding new motherboard:

AMD Athlon X2 370K,
Intel Pentium G3250,
AMD Athlon X4 845,
Intel Pentium G4520

Comment: not really, I already have **4**x 2GB RAM DDR2 as I've said and the on-board lan and I suppose some usb's are fried due to the lightning strikes :)  So I have to rebuild the system and to upgrade a little bit, because even with the LAN disabled in BIOS I can't boot properly and when I succeed, the LAN hardware and some usb's have the error code 10 which also I've tried to solved (hardware failure, another Mobo, and upgrade); I know that there are some good things bout Athlon but I still prefer Intel.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you have 8gb. If you're still feeling slow, you might look into putting PS and your photos on an SSD and also upgrading from a dual core setup to either an Intel i3 or an AMD quad core.

There's nothing wrong with AMD; they're a great choice for budget builds. That being said, if you prefer brand loyalty over saving a few bucks, be my guest. That's why I also recommended the two Pentiums I did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42133/discussion-between-user124853-and-adam-wykes).